# compare two columns in two different files in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

there is a file1 as below:

```
21,2018042100  
22,2018042101  
87,2018042102  
98,2018042103
```

there is file2 as below:

```
45,2018042100      
86,2018042102      
87,2018042103
```

what I need is: (file3)

```
2018042100,21,45    
2018042101,22,0         
2018042102,87,86  
2018042103,98,87
```

in row #2 in file3, data for 2018042101 is exist in file1 but it is not exist in file2. So, 0 is inserted in column $3 which is belong to file2.

kindly please assist to find out how I can create a file like file3.
Thanks.

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `awk`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/).*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join seems like made for that problem:

```
join -t',' -a 1 -a 2 -j 2 file1 file2
2018042100,21,45
2018042101,22
2018042102,87,86
2018042103,98,87
```

except for the missing ",0" in line 2, but maybe you find a solution in the manpage for that problem too. Else you may use sed to correct for that issue.

```
join -t',' -a 1 -a 2 -e "0" -j 2 file1 file2  | sed -r 's/^[^,]+,[^,]+$/&,0/'
2018042100,21,45
2018042101,22,0
2018042102,87,86
2018042103,98,87
```

Answer (score 0):

Another using awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1;next}{print $2,$1,(a[$2]+0)}' file2 file1
2018042100,21,45
2018042101,22,0
2018042102,87,86
2018042103,98,87
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","                # set field separators
}
NR==FNR {                     # process first file
    a[$2]=$1                  # hash value on date
    next                      # process next record in first file
}
{                             # process second file
    print $2,$1,(a[$2]+0)     # output date, value, value from first file if exists
}' file2 file1                # mind the file order
```

Notice, that `(a[$2]+0)` expects the first field value to be a number like in your example. All other values will produce `0`.